# Input "10" Output 1.0 from string to float version 2

Tags: winapi

As a follow up to the dear Robert Harvey who claims it didn't happend.

As almost stated by the subject, I got an edit control which I have predefined with "0.00", I start up my application and enter for an example 10 in the EDIT control, beside the EDIT control I got a BUTTON control which I have this code underneath as the event.
The code underneath will then take the "string" or char array from the EDIT control, convert it to a float with "atof" from the standard C library, and then I write it back to the EDIT control, but this time I dont get 10.0 as expected, I simply get 1.

I have tried with "123" and then I only get 12.0, so the question in simple form would be why will my entered string "10" become 1.00 with the following code and where would I make it right. I take it you dont need further code as you all probably got a working skeleton and past it into or can run the code thru your head without needing to prototype it.

```
char fromTextField[1024];
HWND textfield = GetDlgItem(hwnd,(WM_USER+1001));
int fromTextFieldLength = GetWindowTextLength(textfield);
GetWindowText(textfield,fromTextField,fromTextFieldLength);
float ampl =atof(fromTextField);
char amplitudefromtextfield[100];
_snprintf(amplitudefromtextfield,sizeof(amplitudefromtextfield),"%f",ampl);
SetWindowText(textfield,amplitudefromtextfield);
```

Comment: Are you linking with unicode libs?

Comment: No, Not that Im aware of. I have disabled the character set in VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that the length parameter you're passing to `GetWindowText` is the result from `GetWindowTextLength`. So if `GetWindowTextLength` returns 3, you're passing 3 to `GetWindowText`. But that doesn't include the null terminator. So `GetWindowText` doesn't terminate the string. And there's no telling what might already be in the buffer.

Change your call to:

```
GetWindowText(textField, fromTextField, fromTextFieldLength+1);
```

Comment: Jim Mischel, Thanks alot that was exactly what was needed, I really have to get some sleep, and don't MIX languages.... bad bad me.